# How to do a query with multiple foreign keys pointing to one table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database with two tables (person, item). The person table consists of id, name, and let‘s say 5 item columns with foreign keys referencing to the item table. The item table consists of id, name and description.

I want to do a query now that list the person.id, person.name and the 5 item.name. How can I achieve this? I know something with JOIN but I don‘t get it right now.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with your data model.  You should not be storing lists of items in separate columns.  There are multiple alternatives.  The typical solution is a separate table with one row per person and item.  You can also store the items as arrays or JSON.

But to answer your question, you need multiple joins:

```
select p.*, i1.name as item_name_1, i2.name as item_name_2
from person p left join
     items i1
     on p.item_id_1 = i1.id left join
     items i2
     on p.item_id_2 = i1.id left join
     . . .   -- and so on
```

Comment: Hey Gordon, thanks a lot for your quick answer! I messed around with your example query and at the end I got it (finally). These alias stuff is pretty confusing but it seems like you need them. But your statement about that I have a problem with my data model seems more important for me.

Comment: Let's say I need to store colors selected by an user. Three colors to be exact and the order how they were choosen is also important. The user is only allowed to select specific colors that are stored in the database. I have one table for the user details (id, name etc.) and one table for my colors (id, hex code e.g. #000000 for black, name of the color as string).

I would create a new table with user.id and 3 columns (color_1, color_2, color_3) for the refs to the colors (foreign key = colors.id). The order of the columns (1-3) is the order how the user selected the colors. Any thoughts?

Comment: NO. And this is what Gordan was referring to; normalize your data.  Create a new table with user_id,color_id, color_seq. Color_seq is the defines the sequence of how the user selected the color. You should also backup and redefine the user items similarly.

Comment: @burnie . . . That is one representation and can be useful.  More commonly, this would use a junction table, with one row per user/color and a priority.  Your version can make it a bit challenging to answer questions such as "how many users chose `'yellow'`?"  Or "have both `'blue'` and `'green'`?"

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! It definetely makes more sense for me now why the data model should be set up in the explained way. I also messed around with JSON. Pretty nice stuff. But I have to learn much more about relational databases. Any suggestions for a good book about this topic?